# CiviMember - How to find members that are in a specified group

Tags: civicontribute

Under the Memberships menu, when I try to search for members using "Find Membership" the search options do not allow me to search for members that are within a specific group. I can search per project and other criteria, but it is important for me to have the option to search within a group. Can this be done by some custom hook/coding?

I am currently running CiviCRM  4.5.3 on Wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using advanced search, you can build your own combination of criteria (so you can search contacts on a group AND with specific membership).

By default, it will list the contacts (that belong to that group and have a membership) but (top right corner) you can as well display the result as a list of memberships too

Comment: Ok, thanks Xavier, however, I wanted to have the ability to search for memberships in a group and then select these members and perform actions on them, like send email or do a bulk update via profile. Can it be done in advances search? Also, can this advanced search be saved for later use and made to appear in the Search menu, so users dont need to enter the search criteria every time? Similar to how custom reports can be created once and added as a menu item under Search. It would also be nice if you could perform actions on custom reports. Please comment?

Comment: Yes @Sudesh, you can perform all sorts of actions on the resultset of an advanced search

Comment: @sudesh, can you create new question(s), to keep SE clean and easier to search (and because I'm in full karma wore mode these days ;)